# Facebook comments box loader + size

Tags: facebook

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GEzaD/

Why doesn't the loader disappear? And why can't I see the entire comment box? Did I miss something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to init the Facebook widget:

```
FB.init({
           cookie:true, 
           status:true, 
           xfbml:true, 
           oauth:true
        });
```

Add this `FB.init()` call just before `FB.XFBML.parse();`

If you want to link the plugin to an app you can add an `appId` argument.

Comment: Ok, so an app is required to use the comment box?